# Python Constructor with dict object where value need modification

Tags: python-3.x, constructor

I'm trying to create a constructor that accept dictionary and within the class how will I be able to create method using dict key and value for implementing logic and modification. In below I want to return the list for the list state using the lived_state key and value

```
class StructMyDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self[name]
        except KeyError as e:
            raise AttributeError(e)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value

    def lived(self):
        d= list(self['lived_state'].split(','))
        return(d)

d = {'fname':'John', 'lname': 'Burns', 'Age': 34, 'Gender': None, 'State' : 'CA', 'lived_state' : 'CA,TX,NY,FL'}

v = StructMyDict(**d)
```

Expected output from below print call command

```
print(v.fname) #John
print(v.lname) #Burns
print(v.lived) # return list as ['CA', 'TX', 'NY', 'FL']
print(v.Gender) #''  want this to be '' blank but not None
print(v.address) #AttributeError
```

Current Output

```
John
Burns
<bound method StructMyDict.lived of {'fname': 'John', 'lname': 'Burns', 'Age': 34, 'Gender': None, 'State': 'CA', 'lived_state': 'CA,TX,NY,FL'}>
None
```

Comment: `lived` is a method - you should call it: `print(v.lived())`

Comment: You can add the `@property` decorator to method `lived` to avoid parenthesis in `v.lived()`.

Comment: Thank you guys, both of your solution is working.